# Do I have to reassign a variable with set whenever I append to a list?

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to create a list and append values to it throughout the template. Before having to create a custom filter or something like that I'd like to know how this is done with vanilla Jinja.

This is the only way I could get this to work:

```
{%- set mylist = [] -%}
{# create manipulate variables... #}
{%  set mylist = mylist.append(some_var) %}
{# create manipulate variables... #}
{%  set mylist = mylist.append(some_other_var) %}
```

Do I really need to use set and reassign like this? I'd prefer to just to `{%  mylist.append(some_other_var) %}`, but it looks like that isn't possible?

Also, how can I do multiple appends more concisely (if I don't have another list to loop over). I'd like to do something like this (which does not work):

```
{%  
mylist.append(some_var) 
mylist.append(some_other_var) 
mylist.append(sdfsdfs) 
%}
```

Comment: No. `append()` doesn't return anything, it just modifies the list in place. You're setting `mylist` to `None`.

Comment: You can use `mylist += [some_var, some_other_var, sdfsdfs]` to append multiple variables.

Comment: That does not work in jinja. `{% set mylist += [some_var, some_other_var, sdfsdfs] %}` `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '+'`